How to stretch an image into polygon symbology on QGIS?
I have a world map polygons (vectors) on QGIS 3.28, and i want to add flag on each country.
I have already a svg flag for each country on a field, but flags are represented like a mosaic:

I try to use map units, pixels, points ... but flag are always misplaced and change when i zoom/unzoom.

How to simply stretch the svg on the polygon and fix it for all scales ?

I have found this formula for the width with map units:  array_max (array (bounds_height( $geometry),bounds_width( $geometry)))
Here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/17ubbuv/what_is_the_best_way_to_design_flag_maps_in_qgis/
The result is not perfect, but flags don't move and fill roughly the dimensions of polygons:

